# PayPal Checkout JavaScript: changing currency without redirecting or refreshing page

Tags: paypal

Our website has a checkout flow that would break if redirecting to PayPal for approval. Also we have different currencies so the PayPal SDK will not work for our purposes, since you need to reload to change the currency.

Can we build our own checkout integration opening the URL received from the API side in a new window, or is our only option to use their SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the JS SDK to change the currency, but you don't need to refresh the page.  Here's a short vanilla JS function and example use:

```
function loadAsync(url, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD', function() {
  paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '0.01'
                }
            }]
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // Show a success message to the buyer
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        });
    }

  }).render('body');
});
```

Alternatively, the [paypal-js](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js) package was recently released and does much the same thing

---

Since you mentioned having a server-side API integration, you'll want to use the front-end code of https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server and pair it with two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls . These routes should output only JSON data (no HTML or text)

Comment: hey! thank you for your answer. I see that is kinda the only way to use their sdk like that, but do they allow using custom client integration if we don't want to hack it that way?

Comment: You mean, write your own implementation? Good luck with that.