# How to allow customers pay with different currencies in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to understand how to integrate PayPal Express Checkout in Java, now at first I was successful to apply the scenario where customer approve payment by sending the below request and then getting the approve HATEOAS ref link:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

After that I capture the request where it appears that both customer and seller transactions are okay. But when trying to pay with another `currency_code` like for example `MAD` I get the below error:

> {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"CURRENCY_NOT_SUPPORTED","description":"Currency code is not currently supported. Please refer https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/currency-codes/ for list of supported currency codes."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-CURRENCY_NOT_SUPPORTED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}

Is there any workaround to force multiple currencies on checkout? Or how to implement currency conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAD` is not a PayPal-supported currency

Here is the complete list: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/currency-codes/

If the buyer has a funding source in a different local currency (such as a credit card with `MAD`) a conversion will be shown to them in the checkout. But your transaction must be denominated in one of the PayPal supported currencies, and you will receive that currency.

---

The best approval flow is not link or redirect-based, but rather keeping your site loaded in the background and opening an in-context window.  Here is the front-end UI for that: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

It does require the currency to be known at page load time (or a later [async load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483639/paypal-checkout-javascript-changing-currency-without-redirecting-or-refreshing/63483760#63483760)).

You'll need two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' like in your question, and one for 'Capture Transaction'. There is a guide for them here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: I integrated paypal on server as back-end for mobile app so I do need redirection in my case.

Comment: will it show for customer total amount in USD or MAD? I don't mind that it converts but I want it to show for customer MAD.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. It will only show the conversion if they select a MAD funding source, in which case it has to show both because it is a conversion.

Comment: I meant by my question will it show that for customer on checkout?

Comment: As for the conversion, do you recommend it if I have 2 multiple users getting their commission from transaction?

Comment: If the customer selects a MAD funding source, they will see the conversion to MAD. If they don't select such a funding source, they will not see anything about MAD because there is no reason for them to see anything about MAD.

Comment: 2 multiple users getting their commission has nothing to do with a conversion on the buyer end.

Comment: I meant that some customers or users in my area they don't have visa card for buying with USD only with local currency which is MAD, so do I need to convert the currency from MAD to USD in my end?? and would it work for my case?

Comment: Buyer funding conversion is on the buyer end, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thank you sir, that's what I needed to know I thought I had to do the conversion on my end. But I think I still need to convert the MAD to USD when specifying amount in the request sent to Paypal, right? Because the amount in the platform is shown as MAD and not USD.

Comment: The amount you send to PayPal needs to be in a PayPal-supported currency such as USD, yes https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/currency-codes/