# How to accept payment in requested currency in PayPal through integration via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

Currently, I am able to accept payment only in one currency with this code

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Your Client ID&currency=AUD"></script> -->
```

If make USD over there like this..

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Your Client ID&currency=USD"></script> -->
```

I can accept the payment in USD on my website

if will do GBP

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Your Client ID&currency=GBP"></script> -->
```

I can accept the payment in GBP on my website

But when I add multiple currencies like this...

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Your Client ID&currency=AUD,USD, AUD,NZD,GBP"></script> -->
```

The button doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The currency determines which buttons are eligible, so an SDK load is only usable with 1 currency at a time.

To support multiple currencies, you must [reload the SDK on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483639/paypal-checkout-javascript-changing-currency-without-redirecting-or-refreshing) and re-render any buttons afterward (and createOrder, when called, must specify amounts in the single currency that matches).

---

A new alternative you can try is to load the SDK *multiple* times on the page using the `data-namespace` parameter, to specify a name other than the default `paypal`.

An example....

```
<h3>USD buttons...</h3>
<div id="paypal-button-container-1" />

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypalUSD"></script>
<script>
    paypalUSD.Buttons({
        //...
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-1');
</script>


<hr />


<h3>AUD buttons...</h3>
<div id="paypal-button-container-2" />

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=AUD" data-namespace="paypalAUD"></script>
<script>
    paypalAUD.Buttons({
        //...
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-2');
</script>

</script>
```

In general, unless you have a specific business need to receive multiple currencies in your account, it's simpler to just use an international currency like USD or EUR and let PayPal show the conversion at payment time if the buyer is going to use a funding source in a differrent currency like GBP, NZD, etc